# AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance recovery to specific time

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I want to recover my AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance to 2 days before.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you previously made any Amazon EBS Snapshots of your disk volumes?

Comment: No I dont have EBS Snapshots previously

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not previously make any Snapshots of your Amazon EBS volumes, it is **not possible** to recover the state of the instance to a previous point in time.

An Amazon EBS Snapshot is a backup of the contents of a disk. You might consider taking regular snapshots, or [Automating the Amazon EBS snapshot lifecycle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/snapshot-lifecycle.html).

Comment: Ok, then I can't recovery to 2 days?

Comment: Correct. It is not possible to recover the state of the instance to a previous point in time. It's just like any other computer -- if you did not configure backups, there is no ability to recover.